# JQuery change text on click in comment

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

i have a problem in  the JQuery to change text,

I want to change **fold it** to **expand it**, so that i can show and hide the reply in the comment, while changing the text from **fold it** to **expand it**

This code did work in the first comment but it didn't work to second comment, third comment, etc...

It can show and hide the reply, but it didn't change the text.

this is my code for view:

```
<div id="fold " class="comment-reply-container">
   <p id="fold_p" class="toggle-reply">Fold it</p>
   <div class="comment-reply col-sm-14">

   </div>
</div>
```

this is my code for Javascript:

```
$(".comment-reply-container .toggle-reply").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
        
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#fold").click(function () {
      $("#fold_p").fadeOut(function () {
          $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Fold it') ? 'Expand it' : 'Fold it').fadeIn();
      })
  })
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must not use same id for multiple elements in HTML. This way you will not be able to find correct element and write common logic around it.

Either put unique id for each HTML element or use class for identifying target elements.
Below is the example with `class` for common element and script has been prepared around it.

Replace all ids with `class` name and attach click event to the the toggle element. Find required child element using `$(this)` and perform required operations.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fold").click(function() {
    var $foldP = $(this).find(".fold_p");
    $foldP.fadeOut(function() {
      var text = ($foldP.text() == 'Fold it') ? 'Expand it' : 'Fold it';
      $foldP.text(text).fadeIn();
      $foldP.next().slideToggle("slow");
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fold comment-reply-container">
  <p class="fold_p toggle-reply">Fold it</p>
  <div class="comment-reply col-sm-14">
      Some content 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fold comment-reply-container">
  <p class="fold_p toggle-reply">Fold it</p>
  <div class="comment-reply col-sm-14">
      Some content 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fold comment-reply-container">
  <p class="fold_p toggle-reply">Fold it</p>
  <div class="comment-reply col-sm-14">
      Some content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

First, try to create a function that changes the text when clicked.

Example:

```
const toggleText = 'Fold it'; //make sure the variable's value is exactly the same as the text you are displayed
const expandText = 'Expand it';

function toggleFunction() {
  if ($("#fold_p").text() == toggleText) {
    $("#fold_p").text() = expandText;
  } else {
    $("#fold_p").text() = toggleText;
  }
}
```

And then call the `toggleFunction()` inside your click function, so the function is called when clicked.

Let me know if it works